# android emulator setup not quite right

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I run an app on my android emulator after following a tutorial, my app always looks different than it is supposed to. My default background is white with black text but every other emulator I see on the internet has a default black background with white text. Also when I create a `Spinner` it doesn't have the green selection circles that seem to be default on all the other emulators. I'm using eclipse Juno with android sdk rev 20. It looks like I didn't install something or enable something but I don't know what I'm missing. Here are some pics to show what I mean.

My emulator where I have a `Spinner` being clicked:

[image]
What other emulators seem to look like when `Spinner` is clicked:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an emulator issue but the theme that you have applied to your application and the target SDK that you are running your application. Please change target SDK in the manifest file to 10 or lower and comment or remove the line that applies theme: android:theme="..." Then you should achieve desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the emulator. It's the Android Version you are running on them. By default a Spinner will look like the second image in Android 2.0-2.3.3 and the first picture shows a spinner on Android 4.0+, which in normally like a dropdown menu.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer! Got both at same time, which I could accept yours also.